# How to handle solve java null pointer exception when getIntent.getExtras return null value

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception, null

I have two activity ChatRoom activity and chat_message activty. Inside ChatRoom activity
I have an alertDialog which ask user for their user_name and pass the user_name as string to next activity which is chat_message.

The code for alertDialog Box is

```
private void request_user_name() {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);

builder.setView(input_field);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
          name = input_field.getText().toString();
    }
});

builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.cancel();
        request_user_name();
    }
});

builder.show();
```

}

and I use below code to pass the user_name string

```
intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
```

Below is code in second activity where i receive the extras

```
user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
```

But when user_name is not set, then it app crash with error of java null pointer Exception.

So how to handle the getIntent or how to set the Default username when it receives null value or no value at all??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion : Always use constants for put extra keys. like

```
public static final String EXTRA_USER_NAME = "user_name";
```

Your solution : check if bundle has that key.

```
 String user_name = null;
    if (getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getExtras() !=null && getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME))
        user_name = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name)) {
        // TODO: DO HERE YOUR STUFF
    }
```

Also add `getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getExtras() !=null` if you are not sure to pass extras.

Comment: it throws me an error of  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: Edited my answer Hrithik

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    String user_name="" ; 
    if(getIntent()!=null){
      if(getIntent().hasExtra("user_name")){
      user_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
     }
    }
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name)){
     user_name = "Default"; // Or set your default name
   }
```

`TextUtils` checks if user_name is null of Empty , if yes then you can set your default username otherwise you have your name passed from previous activity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please expain me  a code bit....what is the default user_name here or should I use else statement also here to set default username?

Comment: It is recommended you set default value after taking values from previous screen , as your default value may be overriden by null from previous screen

Comment: it throws me error with user_name might not have initialized on  String user_name ; , so instead i used  String user_name =" ";, and error was resolved. is that correct way to do it or not??

Comment: Yes that is the correct way , it should be a lint error i guess ! .It always good to solve such errors. I have updated the same.

Comment: when I do this way it throws me an error with below  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: I don't think it will throw  this error , there are no arrays involved .Are you sure it is coming in this code , or some other part of code ?

Comment: none of the solution works.....it only works only if i run alertdialog box as the activity starts..but it is kind of annyoing to launch dialog box each time user opens the app....I don't know what other solution might work here is the project https://github.com/miskoajkula/Firebase-RealtimeDatabase-App-Example please have a look

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that one of the models along the way is returning null because it doesn't exist. Now, depending on your code, it could be the intent, the extras or the name.
You have to preemptively check for each value, before assigning the name string.

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null
     && getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name")!=null) {

    user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name");

}
```

But this is really a crude way to do it. What you really want to do is something along the lines of:

```
String name = "";

Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    ExtrasModel extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        name = extras.get("user_name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such details. I really appreciate it...what is the defaut value here if prerivious intent or extras is null valu??

Comment: The default value is an empty string "". It is set with the String name = ""; but you can set it to whatever you want like so: String name = "SuperMan";

Comment: when I paste it on onCreate method, it throws me error on Extrasmodel and .get...how can I solve it.

Comment: I only used ExtrasModel as an example. That class doesn't exist. You should retrieve it to whatever class your .getExtras() returns to. But if it is causing you confusion, just ignore it for now. Delete that line and the if statement after. You should learn how returning values work, though.